# Constant pointer to a constant structure is zero

Tags: c, pointers, struct, constants, cortex-m

I am working on a piece of code developed by others and I am trying to make a structure static. But when debugging it seems the pointer is zero (not pointing a variable that is zero):

```
typedef struct WiFiIP{
    // Keep the following in order!  (pri,sec)
    uint16_t WiFiPrimaryPort;
    uint16_t WiFiSecondaryPort;
    // Keep the following in order!  (pri,sec,sntp)
    char WiFiPrimaryAddress[32];
    char WiFiSecondaryIpAddress[32];
    char WiFiSntpIpAddress[32];
};
static const struct WiFiIP WiFiIPs = {7781,7781,"10.0.0.1","",""};
static const __typeof__ (WiFiIPs.WiFiPrimaryPort)
        * const PortPtr = &WiFiIPs.WiFiPrimaryPort;

static const __typeof__(WiFiIPs.WiFiPrimaryAddress)
    *AddressPtr = &WiFiIPs.WiFiPrimaryAddress;
```

So both `AddressPtr` and `PortPtr` are `0x0`.

I know there are a number of other methods to 'hard code' parameters in code, but in this case the existing code is expecting a pointer to structure and I would like to avoid refactoring.

Please be gentle, I have never been good with pointers, and I know there are a lot of literature on pointers. I have searched and followed a number of examples but am unable to get it to work.

This code is being developed for a cortex-m3 processor

Comment: Both of those variables should be non-null.  There's probably something else going on.  Please update your question with a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: "So both AddressPtr and PortPtr are 0x0." there are not, what debugger do you use ?

Comment: I hate the schooling system that forces a `typedef` down the throat of every C student, even when it does nothing.

Comment: Isn't the optimizer maybe inlining the constant? Then it will make sense that the pointers are null.

Comment: @dbush I should have mentioned that I am working of an arm cortex-m3, so hard to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @LouisCloete you re correct, when I follow through the code it seems that the pointers are being optimized to inline. So this issue is a red herring.

Comment: Perhaps your process startup is not correctly initializing static variables

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen and if I copy your exact code it seems to work as expected for me. Unfortunately you didn't include how *you* are displaying the pointer values.

To properly print the value of a pointer, you can use something like:

```
printf("PortPtr points to memory location at: %#lX\n", (uintptr_t)PortPtr);
printf("AddressPtr points to memory location at: %#lX\n", (uintptr_t)AddressPtr);
```

It this case you should be able to verify the pointers are not initialized to NULL.

Comment: See also: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44f0920475b1afca

Comment: Thanks and sorry for not saying in my original post that I am working on cortex-m3, I have updated the post.

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant, as long as you have printf or an equivalent this code should work fine. I am able to run it on a Cortex-M4 as well...